# How to filter file extensions

Tags: vb.net, file-extension

I'm trying to separate files in a folder by extension, using the code below:

```
Dim file_list3 As String() = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xls")
Dim file_list4 As String() = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xlsm")
```

but all of the ".xls" files end up in list 4 along with the ".xlsm" files. How can I keep the subset of just ".xls" flies out of the list of ".xlsm" files?

Thanks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, are you sure that there is no other code that 'mixes' things?

Comment: No, there is no other code that mixes things. Why the down vote, just because you can't reproduce it?

Comment: see the notes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wz42302f(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This only happens for search with an extension of 3 characters since it also searches the short 8.3 filename

Comment: We should be able to see who down voted a question so as to prevent drive-by's without an explanation. Sorry for the assumption Steve.

Comment: Well, sometimes I feel like you, but it is wise to avoid this. It would trigger an infinite revenge mess. (As someone said, Forget it and move on, it is just a downvote)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
Dim file_list3 = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xls").Where(Function(item) item.ToLower().EndsWith(".xls"))
Dim file_list4 = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xlsm").Where(Function(item) item.ToLower().EndsWith(".xlsm"))
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you are going to do that - you only need one GetFiles call; then create the sublists from that master list

Comment: But I want a separate list of each file type so these are my sublists.

Comment: But you could make one call to the File System, then split the results using Where into 2 separate lists.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to reproduce the behavior documented.
It seems that I have set this command on my working pc

```
fsutil 8dot3name set 0
```

this command disables the creation of the old 8.3 short filenames required at MS-DOS time.
With this configuration the command `Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xls")` returns only the files that have exactly the extension specified and not other extensions that starts with XLS.

Applying the command

```
fsutil 8dot3name set 1
```

I expected to have the same result explained by the OP, but this is not the case with files already in the folder because they were created when the `8dot3name` flag was disabled.
But a new file named `test.xlsm` started to appear between the files returned by the search pattern `*.xls`

So, to fix your problem you could use the [fsutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621566.aspx) command as explained in the article [How to disable 8.3 file name creation on NTFS partitions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121007/en-us) and perhaps strip away the old 8.3 entries with the `strip` option or just use a slight variation of your code above

```
 Dim all_files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xls")
 Dim file_list3 = all_files.Where(Function(x) Path.GetExtension(x).ToLower = ".xls").ToList()
 Dim file_list4 = all_files.Where(Function(x) Path.GetExtension(x).ToLower = ".xlsm").ToList()
```